# Is there a way to serialize a method call

Tags: java, serialization

I am looking for a way to log a method call, store it in a database, and then at a later time execute it.

I was thinking to serialize the method call with all its arguments, store it, and then retrieve it back, deserialize it and execute it some how.

So, I am looking for a generic method that will allow me to store the method call with its arguments. Something like

```
public String myMethod(String arg1, String[] arg2) {

  logMethodCall(thisMethodName, allMethodArgumentsSerialized)

}
```

and the `logMethodCall` would store the info in a database.

So

a) any code that will allow me to dynamically loop all arguments of a method and serialize them?

b) any code to get the current method name dynamically?

c) any other idea to accomplish something similar

Comment: There are *much* better ways of handling this. Could you specify your actual use case so we could help suggest a proper alternative?

Comment: Even if you had a proper solution, calling the method again later would only re-call the same method with the same arguments, which would reserialize the same arguments and method name. So, what's the point?

Comment: @JBNizet I was going to wrap the logMethodCall with some condition: if (condition) { logMethodCall(thisMethodName, allMethodArgumentsSerialized)} else { do rest of code} .... or something like that

Comment: ^^that would have been some good information to include with the question.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the [`Command`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern, where the actual command object is to be persisted (possibly serialized) before being executed:

> command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method parameters

Comment: Designing your code with the command pattern offers a lot more flexibility as well--be sure to have a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, dare I say it, a natural language for handling stuff like this is Lisp. "Code = data", as they say.

If there is a requirement to use Java (for example, if this is to be a small part of a larger system already in Java), consider using ABCL (a Lisp implementation which targets the JVM).

You can spend a lot of time trying to wedge a square peg into a round hole, or just do it the easy way; it's your choice. I really don't mean this in a negative way; it's just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this pattern before, where you save method calls to the database. I have seen delayed method calls and throttled method calls, but those are always in the running app, they don't survive persistently.

If you want to have persistent actions that can be executed in the future, I think the right way to do this is to create some sort of action or edit object, in the same way that javax.swing.undo.AbstractUndoableEdit works. Then you can log these from anywhere, and execute them from anywhere. The actions can work in a few ways, including:

- Store an object type, method name and generic arguments, and execute those later
- Provide specific arguments and call a predetermined method name

I would go with the second with a base class, as Swing does, so from your example you would have a `myMethodAction` class whose objects take the arguments as properties and that knows when told to `execute` that it should call `myMethod`.

I would also not have the `myMethod` implementation do both things. That is going to be a huge headache later. Rather have something like

```
public void myMethod()
{
    if(condition) ... save it ...
    else myMethodNow();
}

public void myMethodNow()
{
   ... do the work now ...
}
```

Hope that helps.